# Returning array of string from JNI to android

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I want to return array of string from JNI to java(actully in android). How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at createStringArray() in [dalvik/dalvikvm/Main.c](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/dalvik.git;a=blob;f=dalvikvm/Main.c;h=a6439fbd7133f2f077298e580e806deff49a376a;hb=HEAD#l44).  In short:

- get the ID for the String class
- pass it to NewObjectArray to create an array of String
- create String objects and stuff them into the array
- return the array